# Is there a closed form exists to count the total number of forests with x number of vertices such that no vertices are adjacent in the orignial graph?

Tags: combinatorics

Given a graph of a horizontal graph as follows:

[image]

In such a graph, I want to efficiently (preferably a closed form) calculate the total number of graphs that can be formed with vertices x<=n (n is the total number of vertices in the original graph), such that none of the vertices in x are adjacent in the original graph.

Is there a closed form exists to calculate the same (given any n and x)?

Currently, I am literally, generating all possible combination of x vertices and then checking if any pair has an edge in the original graph. But this brute force is very expensive and does not scale. Is there a better approach?

Comment: This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2945440); I'm saying this just in case somebody answers there.